# Problema com "phonegap run android"

Tags: apache-cordova

Tendo ambiente configurado, e usando o comando "**phonegap run android**" tenho o seguinte erro:

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run android'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova run android'
```

Esperava que abrisse um hello world na tela do device mas não abre.

Comment: Comando phonegap run android

Comment: Antes de executar `phonegap run android` execute `adb devices` para verificar se o seu aparelho é encontrado pelas ferramentas do SDK.

Comment: Quando executo "adb devices"  o console informa que esse não é um comando interno ou externo.

Comment: Adicione o path do SDK do Android `C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` a variável `Path` em Variáveis de ambiente. Se der certo rode os comandos `adb kill-server` e `adb start-server`. Feito isso rode novamente `adb devices`.

Comment: Isso já foi feito.

Answer (score 3):

Isto não é um erro. Recomendo que use o comando `cordova run android`, ele é mais verboso.

Algo muito importante é seu device estar em modo desenvolvedor ativado.